# Left Side Windows 10 Task Bar Mucking with Windows Opening Position

Tags: windows-10, firefox, taskbar

I prefer the task bar on the left of the display to maximize the vertical use of the screen.  I find some apps don't understand properly and do not open in the precise location they were closed at.

Windows Explorer is a good example.  A window that opens automatically after a shutdown (or a new one) is always opened a bit to the right, maybe five or ten pixels.  Same with a command window and more than one browser.  Firefox is off by some hundred pixels.

A few apps manage this properly, like Excalibur, a calculator.

Any idea what's going on?  I've used my task bar on the left for some 8 years or so and had the same problem under Win8.  Is a left side task bar just doomed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the left-side taskbar is doomed, as Windows 11 only supports it at
the bottom.

If you intend to upgrade to Windows 11 in the future, better get used to
the taskbar residing at the bottom.

Comment: I have no interest in using Windows 11.  However, a registry edit seems to be possible that allows the taskbar to be positioned on the left side of the screen.

Comment: So what's the question? Fixing apps positioning?

Comment: **Any idea what's going on? I've used my task bar on the left for some 8 years or so and had the same problem under Win8. Is a left side task bar just doomed?**  Yes, I'm asking how to prevent the windows from being opened somewhere other than where they are set to be opened.

Comment: This is a Windows bug that wasn't fixed for many years, and probably has no chance to be fixed now that Windows 11 has removed the left-side taskbar. I can't help you with this.

Comment: I don't really give a rat's rear about windows 11...for the foreseeable future anyway.  But there are ways to get the taskbar on the left according to various web sites.  I think it requires registry entry edits.  It's not like they took the code out of the base.  For who knows what reason they just turned it off in the setup.  Goofy!

Comment: If your computer is eligible, sooner or later you will move to Windows 11 because of new features, trust Microsoft in that. As regarding registry edits, yes, they are know, but: [Windows 11 Lets You Move the Taskbar to the Left or Right, But It’s Broken](https://www.howtogeek.com/760036/windows-11-lets-you-move-the-taskbar-to-the-left-or-right-but-its-broken/).

Comment: No, I don't have a reason to migrate.  This is a new computer and it offers to upgrade me, but I'm one of the very few who are happy with Windows 10.  Updating major releases always have significant risk of breaking existing software and I have enough trouble keeping software working as it *should*, so until Windows 11 becomes a cure for cancer, I'm not upgrading.

Comment: It's wise to wait 6 months after a new release, although Microsoft always wins in the end. In any case, my answer stands: What you see is what you'll get forever, because Microsoft is not going to improve anything in the Start menu of Windows 10.

Comment: Except you don't know that.   Besides, it doesn't require Microsoft to provide it.  I recall in Windows 8 they significantly changed the look and feel of the taskbar.  Third party software started providing the old look and feel.